# Why does qt-creator need to connect to google-analytics?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I just installed `qt-creator` to work on non-qt C++ projects. The installed version is **2.5.0** (Based on Qt 4.8.2 32-bit)

If I click on any of these pages:
[image: image showing qt-creator home page links]

I get this error:
[image: image showing the error]

I realized that `/etc/hosts` file has the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1  www.google-analytics.com
```

I don't want to remove the entry from the hosts file because it's always been there along with thousands of other similar adservices/porn/malware addresses.

I do not intend to say that `qt-creator` is looking to create problems in my computer, but I am genuinely interested to know why `qt-creator` needs to connect to google-analytics? Can this be disabled and `qt-creator` can still be functional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is said by Qt employees that Google Analytics code used to be included in Qt documentation (and pages you are viewing as part of it), but was removed afterwards ([source](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/10038/)).

Try upgrading Qt creator to the most recent version (2.5.2 in repos / 2.6.0 http://qt-project.org/downloads) and see if this solves your problem.

Apart from that, I'd say pretty much any IDE tries to collect usage statistics if you allow it to. Check out if this can be configured in Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem installing the [qtcreator-doc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtcreator-doc/) package:

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator-doc
```

Comment: I asked a question about why analytics was needed. Pavel has answered it accurately. So I marked his answer as the correct answer. I posted this answer as I was later able to solve the problem without resorting to removing the entry in hosts file. My answer is about how I was able to solve the problem. In posting my own answer I might help others who have similar problem. Any way, thanks for explaining your down vote.